# 301 Redirect Any Segment to First Segment

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, expressionengine, segments

Im trying to redirect pages such as:

> /selected-work/project-name-1
>   /selected-work/project-name-2
>   /selected-work/project-name-3
>   /selected-work/category/category-name

to just

> /work/

Is there a 301 redirect I can use that will notice it has a segment AFTER the first, and redirect ALL?

Using .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to sort this by doing:

> RedirectMatch 301 ^/selected-work(.*)$
>   http://www.website.co.uk/work

Which now redirects any sub-folders after /selected-work/ to /work/